# scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDDPartition.inputPartitions

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm trying to get data from mongodb via spark, but I'm getting an error. I'm running spark driver locally from idea, master and workers nods are running in docker. These nodes are located on the local VM.
Google seems to say that most likely the error is in some kind of dependency, but I can’t figure out which one. Analyze Maven tree does not find critical problems

exception

```
23/04/20 14:48:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.19.0.6 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDDPartition.inputPartitions of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDDPartition
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:507)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Added dependency mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.1.1 to spark docker /opt/spark/jars

```
public static SparkConf buildSparkConf() {
        return new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("spark://192.168.56.1:9013")
                .setAppName("test")
                .set("spark.local.ip","192.168.56.1")
                .set("spark.ui.port","9016")
                .set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0")
                .set("spark.driver.port", "9360")
                .set("spark.blockManager.port", "9260")
                .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "30")
                .set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", "1073741824")
                .set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")
                .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.56.1/test.bigData")
                .set("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://192.168.56.1/test.bigData")
                .set("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://192.168.56.1/test.bigData")
                .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.1.1")
                .set("spark.driver.host","192.168.56.1");
    }

    public void test() {
        SparkSession sparkSession =  SparkSession.builder()
                .config(buildSparkConf())
                .getOrCreate();

        sparkSession.read()
                .format("mongodb")
                .load()
                .show(false);
    }
```

maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

scala version 2.12.15

spark version 3.3.1

mongo version 4.4.20

I ask for help in this matter, what should I pay attention to?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [package](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12) of dependencies and added them to the jars /opt/spark/jars folder